# codeigniter multiple checkbox update where user id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to ask, my problem is how to update all data in the form of checkbox in the table and save it with one button sampled to the database in the form of "true" text = checkbox on / "false" = checkbox = off, following display and code

display:

[image]

red circle button to update all data in the table

class setting_c extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    //validasi jika user belum login

}
public function index() {
  $this->load->model('user_model');
    $data['user_data'] = $this->user_model->getall();
    $this->load->view('pages/setting', $data);
}

 public function save_edit(){

    if (isset($_POST['btn-edit'])) {


        $ur  = $this->input->post('ckls');
        $ad  = $this->input->post('ad[]');
        $ed  = $this->input->post('ed[]');
        $dd  = $this->input->post('dd[]');
        $xd  = $this->input->post('ao[]');
        $id  = $this->input->post('eo[]');
        $pd  = $this->input->post('do[]');
        $ao  = $this->input->post('xd[]');
        $eo  = $this->input->post('id[]');
        $do  = $this->input->post('pd[]');


        $jml_username = count($ur);
        for ($i=0;$i<$jml_username;$i++){
        if(isset($ad[$i])){
            $ad[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $ad[$i] = "False";
        };

        if(isset($ed[$i])){
            $ed[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $ed[$i] = "False";
        };

        if(isset($dd[$i])){
            $dd[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $dd[$i] = "False";
        };
        if(isset($ao[$i])){
            $ao[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $ao[$i] = "False";
        };

        if(isset($eo[$i])){
            $eo[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $eo[$i] = "False";
        };

       if(isset($do[$i])){
            $do[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $do[$i] = "False";
        };

        if(isset($xd[$i])){
            $xd[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $xd[$i] = "False";
        };

        if(isset($id[$i])){
            $id[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $id[$i] = "False";
        };

        if(isset($pd[$i])){
            $pd[$i] = "True";
        }else{
            $pd[$i] = "False";
        };


        $data[$i] = array(
                'AddData' => $ad[$i],
                'EditData' => $ed[$i],
                'DeleteData' =>  $dd[$i],
                'AddOcc' =>  $ao[$i],
                'EditOcc' =>  $eo[$i],
                'DeleteOcc' =>  $do[$i],
                'ExportData' =>  $xd[$i],
                'ImportData' =>  $id[$i],
                'PrintData' =>  $pd[$i]
            );
        $this->db->where('Username', $ur[$i]);
        $this->db->update('utililas_telkom', $data[$i]);  
        }

        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', $ad1);
        redirect('setting_c');
    }else{
        redirect('setting_c');
    }

 }
```

}

view

```
 <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Data </h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
          <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg');?>
         <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('setting_c/save_edit') ?>" id="form-delete">
          <table id="search1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Select</th>
              <th>User Name</th>
              <th>Add Data</th>
              <th>Edit Data</th>
              <th>Delete Data</th>
              <th>Add OCC</th>
              <th>Edit OCC</th>
              <th>Delete OCC</th>
              <th>ExportData</th>
              <th>ImportData</th>
              <th>PrintData</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($user_data->result_array() as $i):
              $username = $i['Username'];
              $ad = $i['AddData'];
              $ed = $i['EditData'];
              $dd = $i['DeleteData'];
              $ao = $i['AddOcc'];
              $eo = $i['EditOcc'];
              $do = $i['DeleteOcc'];
              $xd = $i['ExportData'];
              $id = $i['ImportData'];
              $pd = $i['PrintData'];
            ?>
          <tr>  
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckls[]"  value="<?php echo $username; ?>"></td>         
              <td><?php echo $username; ?></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="ad[]" <?php echo ($ad=='True'||$ad=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> ></td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="ed[]" <?php echo ($ed=='True'||$ed=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="dd[]" <?php echo ($dd=='True'||$dd=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="ao[]" <?php echo ($ao=='True'||$ao=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="eo[]" <?php echo ($eo=='True'||$eo=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="do[]" <?php echo ($do=='True'||$do=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="xd[]" <?php echo ($xd=='True'||$xd=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" <?php echo ($id=='True'||$id=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="pd[]" <?php echo ($pd=='True'||$pd=='true')?"checked":"" ;?> > </td>
          </tr>


            <?php  endforeach;?>
            </tbody>

          </table>
           <div class="col-xs-4">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" name="btn-edit">Save Data</button>

            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <a href="<?php echo base_url('setting_c'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" >Reload Data
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-body -->
      </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

database

[image]

please help, thank you

Comment: what is the issue now?

Comment: so what is your problem now? 

ask questions completely with full commenting please.